# Selecting coordinates from text in Python

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list in Python where the first item maps a route taken by a walker. The '0' is the starting point of the walk and the '68' represents the first waypoint. The walker will always finish back where it started.

As a result, the points between the start and end points can be seen as the intermediary points or waypoints of the walk.

```
['Route 0: 0([1.11, 2.11]) ->  68([5.11, -6.11]) ->  0([1.11, 2.11]) Service Time(53) Time(1:54, 24:0)\n',
'item 2\n',
'item 3\n',
'item 4\n']
```

Is there a way that I can grab each coordinate in the first item of my list and print them to a CSV by marking them as either a start, end or intermediary point?

I tried specifying that each coordinate is preceded by a '([' in the 1st item but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: The output I expect is all the pairs of coordinates.

Comment: Please see if my suggested edit matches what you've had in mind.

Comment: Yes it pretty much what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read the question right, you are trying to match *digits***([***something***,***something***])**:

```
import re
data = [
    'Route 0: 0([1.11, 2.11]) ->  68([5.11, -6.11]) ->  0([1.11, 2.11]) Service Time(53) Time(1:54, 24:0)\n',
    'item 2\n',
    'item 3\n',
    'item 4\n']

matches = re.findall(r'(\d+)\(\[(.+?),(.+?)\]\)', data[0])
coords = [(int(p), float(x), float(y)) for p, x, y in matches]
print(coords)
# [(0, 1.11, 2.11), (68, 5.11, -6.11), (0, 1.11, 2.11)]
```

Then you can loop over that list and put it into CSV.